# Path to dynamic libraries in ROS root system

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have two problems that I need some help:

**First**: find the PATH of dynamical libraries setup by ROS packages in the root of the system. For example, I have the gazebo_ros_pkgs package, which was setup by:

> sudo apt-get install  ros-indigo-gazebo7-ros-pkgs

and I want to find the location of the follow library:

> libgazebo_ros_camera.so

**Second**: find the PATH of dynamical libraries setup by GAZEBO with the command:

> sudo apt-get install libgazebo6-dev.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249139/path-to-dynamic-libraries-in-ros-root-system/) by [JoaoPedro](https://answers.ros.org/users/12316/joaopedro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2016-11-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't really see any difference between the two cases you give us (both are installed system-wide by the `apt` package manager, they're not 'setup' by ROS nor Gazebo).

On Debian/Ubuntu, you could use something like `dpkg -S <name_of_the_file>` to find both the package name and the location of the file. In your case:

```
dpkg -S libgazebo_ros_camera.so
```

Alternatively, you could use a command like `locate libgazebo_ros_camera.so`, which should give you the location as well (but it depends on whether the db has been updated).

To find out what files were installed by `apt` for a specific package, you could use:

```
dpkg -L libgazebo6-dev
```

you could add `| grep .so` to find just the shared libraries, or `| grep lib` to find all occurrences of *lib* in the listing.

PS: note that this is not a ROS-specific problem, but rather a question about interacting with the `apt` package manager on a Debian/Ubuntu system.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JoaoPedro](https://answers.ros.org/users/12316/joaopedro/) on 2016-12-03**:\

Thank you for the help gvdhoorn . Now I understand the package manager. These commands solved my problem.